# Signal distortion due to impedance mismatch

Tags: electromagnetism, electrical-resistance, signal-processing

Does impedance mismatch only reduces the power transmission efficiency or it gives rise to signal distortion also? Can anyone please explain this in detail?

Comment: I can definitely help with this, but please ask something more specific. Impedance mismatch in what? A coaxial cable? Be as specific as possible.

Comment: Yes, it's a coaxial cable, with characteristic impedance Zo. The line connects a sender with output impedance Zt  and a receiver with input impedance Zr. So, I wanted to know under which conditions will there be a signal distortion.

Comment: Ok so there are *two* impedance mismatches in the system, one at the interface between the sender and the transmission line, and another at the interface between the transmission line and the receiver. Correct?

Answer (score 1):

By itself a mismatch only changes the power (signal level) transferred. But practically speaking, a modulated signal gets distorted by a mismatched transmission line that is longer than a fraction of the shortest wavelength. This is because the more complex wave in that signal has other copies of itself added at different phases. Also, a driving circuit may react non-linearly to the mismatch (and/or be damaged by the reflected power). And finally a change in amplitude at the receiver may affect its ability to demodulate if there is noise present that is not proportionally changed, and/or its AGC is not perfect.

Comment: The first statement *"By itself a mismatch only changes the power (signal level) transferred"* seems misleading to me. Impedance mismatches cause reflection which make the transfer of the system depend on frequency. As soon as that's the case, any non-continuous-wave signal gets distorted.